# How do I add code in Salesforce 1?

Tags: jquery-mobile, salesforce

I am a beginner in the Salesforce 1 platform.  I started this internship and I am being asked to create a jQuery Mobile app in Salesforce 1.  I have learned how to build the app, but I am lost as to how to add code to it.  I am a beginner developer being asked to recreate a Mobile app that is more for someone with more experience.  I am not going to give up, because I know this is a good learning experience for me.  The Salesforce resources have not been helpful to me.  Can you help me try to figure out how to get started with this?  Do I connect the app to a Salesforce page or is there another developing tool I am missing?  Also I cannot add the jQuery Mobile library to be able to get my code to work.  How does that app connect to the code?  I am confused how the objects and fields relate to the code I write for the app.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a VF page, create a tab and assign the VF page to that tab. The VF page should be "Mobile Ready" i.e. you should check the checkbox when you create the VF page. For jQuery libraries, you have to add them as static resources.

Please let me know in case you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have attached the VF page to my Tab.  I need this to be an IOS mobile app.  The only thing is that I have not Mac computer.  I only have an Ipad mini.  Can I still develop the app on a Windows computer and does this make the process in Salesforce different?  I really hope not too much because I have had one heck of a time learning how to just build apps in Salesforce.  Is there any resources for a newbie like me programming a jQuery IOS mobile app in the apex programming environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the other user is correct. Upload the "min" version of the jQuery as a static resource to invoke jQuery on your Visualforce page.

As for designing mobile apps on the Salesforce platform, you need to know quite a bit:

1. MVC model in Salesforce
2. Apex, SOQL, SOSL
3. Visualforce controllers
4. Visualforce
5. HTML and DOM
6. CSS
7. JavaScript
8. Possibly the Mobile SDK for Salesforce
9. Possibly Canvas for Salesforce
10. Possibly XML for Flexipages

If you look on developer.salesforce.com, you'll find learning resources for all of these topics. There's even a workbook for you: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf.

Google's browser offers a mobile emulator for iOS so that developers can develop on one platform and test on many platforms. Its is difficult to use though, imho. It has quite a learning curve.